# Requirejs: Remove/delete build.txt after build

Tags: requirejs

After successfully optimizing and building the modules using r.js library, you would find the file build.txt with the summary of all the modules and its dependencies.

I don't want this build.txt file to reach the production server.

Apart from manually deleting the build.txt, is there any way to suppress or remove this file?

Manual deletion is not the answer that I am looking for as you might forget to delete it sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been requested: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/pull/722/files

To use it, you would add the following option to your build.js file:

```
noBuildTxt: true
```

As Louis points out, it hasn't actually been added :/

If you want, you can do what I did and restructure your application so you don't need a modules property, add the noBuildTxt option and then *pretend* it works. (Removing the modules property was what got rid of the module definitions, not the noBuildTxt)

Comment: Your link points to an *open* pull request. The request has not been handled, which means that the feature is not part of RequireJS.

Comment: @Louis I know what an open pull request is, I just had a brain fart and didn't realize it wasn't closed :( I found this question, found the issue through google, tried adding the option in the issue to my build.js file and it worked, so I thought the question was answered and moved on with my project.

Comment: It "worked"? If you use the option with the `r.js` that is released by James Burke, the option will be ignored (no effect on `build.txt`). If you used the version that the author of the pull request used, that's another matter.

Comment: @Louis It "worked". Turns out I had removed the module property in build.js before adding the option.

Comment: In r.js 2.2.0, it's `writeBuildTxt`

Answer (score 3):

As I understood [the source cod](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/dist/r.js#L22811)e, there is no way to prevent the creation of the build.txt.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for pointing the relevant line in the file r.js.  I commented that line (file.saveUtf8File(config.dir + "build.txt", buildFileContents);) and it solved the issue for me.